# Object's unique identifier (translate from hexadecimal into decimal)

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, object

I'm learning Python (classes at this momment). On [this](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch13.html) site (bottom of the page) first exercise (under 13.7. Exercises) says:

> Create and print a Point object, and then use id to print the object's unique identifier. Translate the hexadecimal form into decimal and confirm that they match.

I need help with this because I'm not quite sure I understand what I have to do.

If I do:

```
class Point:
    pass

print Point()
print id(Point)
```

I get this output:

```
<__main__.Point instance at 0xb71c496c>
3072094252
```

So, should I do this first part of exercise like this or? And what now? I assume that this second line is decimal number (Am I right?). But what with the first line? How to translate it into decimal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Translate the second number into hexadecimal with the [`hex()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) then test if it is present in the first:

```
p = Point()
hexadecimal_id = hex(id(p))
present = hexadecimal_id in repr(p)
```

Note that I first *store a reference* to the `Point()` instance; otherwise you'd get a new one with potentially a new `id()` value.

Also, don't confuse the class with the instance; the class is an object in its own right, and as such has a `id()` value too.

To go the other way, you'd have to parse out the hexadecimal string; if you are going to assume it is the part after the last space that's doable as:

```
hexadecimal_id = repr(p).rpartition(' ')[-1][:-1]
present = int(hexadecimal_id, 16) == id(p)
```

Here, the [`str.rpartition()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) splits on the last space, and we take whatever comes after it with `[-1]` (last element), then shorted *that* result by one character to remove the `>` character at the end.

Once you have the hexadecimal number you can interpret it as an integer with the [`int()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), specifying the base as 16.

Demo:

```
>>> class Point:
...     pass
... 
>>> p = Point()
>>> id(p)
4300021632
>>> hex(id(p))
'0x1004d1f80'
>>> p
<__main__.Point instance at 0x1004d1f80>
>>> hex(id(p)) in repr(p)
True
>>> # the other direction
... 
>>> repr(p).rpartition(' ')[-1][:-1]
'0x1004d1f80'
>>> hexadecimal_id = repr(p).rpartition(' ')[-1][:-1]
>>> int(hexadecimal_id, 16)
4300021632
>>> int(hexadecimal_id, 16) == id(p)
True
```

Comment: Well, this definitely works, but how to do it vice versa? I mean FROM hexadecimal INTO decimal?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić: in that case you'd have to parse out the hexadecimal string first; I'll update but it is more work than I'd expect you have to do for that exercise.

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić: added a simple method to grab just the hexadecimal string from the representation.

Comment: Something made me read this question (and your answer) again. Thanks for helping me back then. :)